# SQL Server Define Relationship between the same table

Tags: sql-server, relationship

I would like to know if it's ok to define a relationship for a column of a table and say it's a foreign key of the same id column from the table.

Example:

```
Tbl. Name: Categories
Column 1: id
Column 2: name
Column 3: parent_id
```

Parent_id should contain (only if it's necessary) the id of the category.

I want to make a tree structure of my categories.

Is it ok to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when it is appropriate. Which it is in the case you describe for a `Parent-Child` relation of the same table.